# kill all processes with specific name

Tags: bash, ubuntu-16.04

I used to use the following command line code to kill all processes

```
kill `ps -ef| grep -i selenium | grep -v grep| awk '{print $2}'`
```

but that does not work in ubuntu16

can someone pls help?

Comment: This seems like a subject not suited for SO as it's not about programming; you could instead try the SuperUser or Unix/Linux sister sites.

Comment: Use `pkill`, see the link below:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91527/whats-the-difference-between-pkill-and-killall

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with `killall selenium`?

Comment: As far as I know, Selenium is a Java executable and so the parent command name will be Java.

Comment: @RamanSailopal you're probably right. My answer is valid for a given specific name, as stated in the question title, but probably not for this case.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are reading a number of returned results into a variable, you will need to reference the returned output with quotation marks and so:

```
kill "$(ps -ef| grep -i selenium | grep -v grep| awk '{print $2}')"
```

You can also kill process one by one with:

```
ps -ef| grep -i selenium | grep -v grep| awk '{print "kill "$2}' | sh
```

Such strategies can be dangerous though and as others have suggested, try and use pkill where ever possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
pkill selenium
```